# Nginx not proxying to app on localhost 404

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, virtual-machine

I have the following set up,

Nginx is running on an ubuntu vm accessible by other vms through port 80. I am running prestashop in a container accessable only by 127.0.0.1:8080 on the ubuntu vm.

```
UserVM ----> Ubuntu Nginx ----> WebApp container
             |                  |
     192.168.238.171:80    127.0.0.1:8080
```

I am trying to get Nginx to proxy 192.168.238.171/site to 127.0.0.1:8080 where the app is hosted.

My current Nginx config is this:

```
    server {
            listen  80;

            location /site/ {
                    rewrite ^/site(.*) /$1 break;
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
            }
    }
```

This results in a  404. I have tried to configure it to just proxy without the path:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

But this just results in the default nginx install success page.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files, and check that the only `server` block that appears is yours. Also, check the access log and error log for useful information.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out there was another server block being loaded. After commenting it out my browser was complaining about a redirect issue. I fixed that by removing the rewrite line and changing 127.0.0.1:8080 to localhost:8080. Everything is working as needed now.

Answer (score 0):

Another server block was being loaded. Removing it/commenting it out solved it but caused my browser to give a redirect error which was further solved by removing the url rewrite and changing 127.0.0.1:8080 to localhost:8080 in the proxy_pass